# addOperationWithBlock:, how to add operations to a queue within a while loop

Tags: iphone, nsoperationqueue

I have a long running task that reads a file from the documents directory, parses it, deletes the file, then reads the next file from the doc directory, parses, deletes.  I'm trying to put this code in the background but having trouble.  I got so far as:

(pseudocode)

```
while (fileExistsInDocDirectory) {
                NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
                [queue setName:@"LongTask"];
                [queue addOperationWithBlock:^{
                    parseSuccessful = [self doLongTask];                    
                }];
                [queue addOperationWithBlock:^{
                    [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
                        [self updateProgress];                    
                    }];

                }];    
}
```

It will work for one file only since I'm using FMDB my doLongTask is inserting rows into the db.  So when the next queue comes in and tries to insert its data and the db is already in use, it doesn't work.  Am I able to not run the 2nd queue until the first one finishes within a while loop?  I saw some thing about setting up dependent queues, but wasn't sure if there was an easy way to do it without subclassing NSOperation.  Thanks!

Comment: What's the point in creating a separate queue for each and every task? Didn't you mean to create ONE queue outside of the `while` loop and enqueue tasks on that? That would sort out the FMDB issue as well, since tasks on the queue are executed in a strict serial order.

Comment: want to post the answer of how you solved this?